# Show content of two textboxes in a third textbox in real time

Tags: javascript

I have 2 textboxes: Box1 and Box2.

Using JavaScript I would like a third box to show: "ContentOfBox1 metre x ContentOfBox2 metre" in real time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place an onchange event on both your text boxes like so

```
<input id="text1" onchange="modifyText3" />
<input id="text2" onchange="modifyText3" />
<input id="text3" />
```

Then your javascript would be

```
function modifyText3()
{
    var val1 = document.getElementById("text1").value;
    var val2 = document.getElementById("text2").value;
    document.getElementById("text3").value = val1 + " meter x " + val2 + " meter";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I assume you mean "document.getElementById("text3").value"?

Comment: Ash, I think you want "+" instead of "&" when you're combining the values and strings.

Comment: @Michael - Sorry, copy and paste mistake :). @Wesley - Sorry again, just been coding in vbscript :)

Comment: I was under the impression that .getElementById functioned only on 'ids' whereas here you are calling it on the name attribute.  Learn something new everyday I suppose

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 text boxes and add js function "changeOutput" on onChange event of 2 input boxes.

```
<input id="input1" onchange="changeOutput()" value="" />
<input id="input2" onchange="changeOutput()" value="" />
<input id="output" value=""/>
```

And the javascript function is

```
function changeOutput(){
    var input1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
    var input2 = document.getElementById("input2").value;
    document.getElementById("output").value = val1 + " metre x " + val2 + " metre";
}
```